# Loading/Removing Div on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 4 divs on a page, and I want to hide all of them but one, kind of like a slideshow, and when I click the button it loads the next picture. Is there a way to do this with a `<div>`? Loading the first by default with a button that allows the next one to be loaded and the first one to be removed from the page, and preferably cycles through?

Comment: Always only 4 divs? Never more, never less?

Comment: It could vary, 1 to a set maximum amount allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this js.  I just discovered this particular technique, but there are other ways if this does not suit.

```
$('#prev').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').prev().addClass("ind");
        $(".num.ind").next().removeClass("ind");
});

$('#next').click( function() {
    $('.num.ind').next().addClass("ind");
         $(".num.ind").prev().removeClass("ind");
});
```

Here's a fiddle with text instead of images, but it would be trivial to replace with images:
http://jsfiddle.net/7jsojqbq/1/

Comment: If i could upvote you, I would. This seems perfect for what I need! You rock!

Comment: How did you get it working on your page? I copied and pasted it to my page and it's not working. I even included the current version of jquery they used.

Comment: Apologies again, my last comment ignored the fact that you had indeed referenced jquery in your code. You have the css in there too?

Comment: Just updated with images, in case it helps at all: http://jsfiddle.net/7jsojqbq/7/ But could there be another conflicting script in your page?

Comment: Yeah, I have that included too. Styling seems to be working, but when I click the button, it doesn't perform the action.

Comment: I'm so sorry I have to go, but if you have to choose, you might want to accept bloodyKnuckles' answer since his was pure js, which is what you asked for, and mine wasn't.  Good luck!

Comment: I think you might be right, but I can't seem to find the script that is messing with it.

Comment: I was fooling around with this yesterday and made a thing in pure js, thought I'd share because kittens: http://jsfiddle.net/5vapyt14/

Comment: That's pretty impressive @reggie user. How hard is it to add a previous button?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the image DIVs and loop through them hiding all except the first. Then get the button and attach to it's click event another loop through the DIVs that looks for one that's not hidden. When found do a couple things, first hide it, second set a flag for the next loop. On the next loop, with the flag set, display the current DIV, and reset the flag.

If the flag is still set after the loop has run, it means we need to display the first image DIV.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fsgvudyg/)

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
Array.prototype.slice.call(divs).forEach(function(elem, idx) {
    if ( idx ) {
        elem.style.display = 'none'
    }
})

var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var found = 0
    Array.prototype.slice.call(divs).forEach(function(elem) {
        if ( found ) {
            elem.style.display = 'block'
            found = 0
        }
        else if ( elem.style.display !== 'none' ) {
            elem.style.display = 'none'
            found = 1
        }
    })
    if ( found ) { divs[0].style.display = 'block' }
})
```

Example HTML:

```
<div><img src="..."/></div>
<div><img src="..."/></div>
<div><img src="..."/></div>
<div><img src="..."/></div>

<button>Next</button>
```

The script doesn't care how many DIVs there are.